# Azure Publish vs Package - Certificate Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

When I 'publish' my solution to azure from visual studio, the instances are created and assigned a certificate from the local cert store "Windows Azure Tools Certificate".  However when I package the solution and upload manually via the portal, the deployment fails complaining that there is no corresponding certificate with the specified thumbprint.

I need to provide a 'proof of concept' deployment package to a vendor for them to install on their local azure environment for testing, but I'm not sure how to approach the certificate issue.

- Is there a way to include the certificate in the deployment package package?
- When did the "Azure Tools Certificate" in my local certificate store get created?
- What is the best approach to providing a deployment package to a third party to ensure the valid certificates are in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Azure Tools Certificate is the RDP certificate that is automatically created for you.  You can remove RDP from the package and then send a clean package to them with no certificates.  If they want to enable RDP on that package then they can just deploy it to Azure and then turn on RDP in the configuration dashboard for that service.

Comment: Ah so the Certificates are only there to enable RDP?  The strange thing is I unchecked the "Remote Desktop...." checkbox when I'm creating the package, but the entries still appear in the ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg

Comment: To remove the RDP settings you need to right-click the Cloud Service project and select 'Configure Remote Desktop'.  You can then uncheck the 'Enable connections for all roles' and this will remove all the entries from cscfg/csdef.